# Json Removing Leading zeros

Tags: android, json

Quick and probably stupid question here, 
I am pulling JSON data from my server and displaying it in my app in edit texts

I am using volley to GET the data, the JSON data are Dates in the fomat of MM/dd/YYYY so lets say its for ex. 03/12/2020,

but now  My problem is my App displays it as 3/12/2020 and postman does the same, so the 0 goes missing but i am pulling the data directly from my SQL , which includes the 0,

I have learned that Json Removes leading 0's for various reasons,

But how can I add the 0 back to the json within android java using volley

Will Post Code if needed

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK date, formatted like this, should easily be parsed so that you get object of class `Date` or something similar. After you have this, you can format it any way you want (depends on the object being used, though).